# Имеет ли право фабрика создавать зависимости для создаваемого объекта?

Tags: c#, .net

Допустим, у меня есть репозиторий реализованный на Dal уровне, который в конструкторе имеет зависимость от IContextFactory.

На Dal уровне я делаю фабрику этого репозитория, которая имеет метод

```
IRepository Create(ConnectionSettings settings)
{
   return new Repository(new ConcreateContext(settings));
}
```

И тут встает вопрос:

А я имею право так делать или по хорошему мне нужна еще фабрика фабрик, которая прокинется в фабрику создания Репозитория, где в метод Create я передам необходимые параметры?

Comment: Не люди служат паттернам, а паттерны - людям.

Comment: Можно и так и так, просто оцените, где потом может быть придется дописывать или переписывать код, где будут юнит-тесты. И если для "по-хорошему" есть смысл, значит делайте. Наворачивание архитектуры всякими фабриками фабрик обычно делается не потому что паттерн такой, должны быть другие причины.

Comment: зачем вам нужна фабрика? В чем проблема создать репозиторий без фабрики?